# Tomcat deploy: make included scripts executable

Tags: linux, tomcat, ant

I'm devellopping a WebApplication (for Tomcat) using netbeans on Windows 7. For the Webapplication to run I need to run a insall-script once.

This script (*.bat for windows and *.sh for linux is included in my war-file (WEB_INF).

Now everytime I deploy the WAR-file and want to run the script on linux I have to call

```
chmod +x install.sh
```

first.

Is there a way that this script can be made executable by default? I don't want to have to execute some extra commands after the deploy to make the script executable.

For clarification:
I'm not new to Linux and I know how to set executable-rights on files. That's not the problem. My problem is: What do I have to do, so that this script is executable right after tomcat deployed my *.war-file (unpacked it). If I would be using Linux for development as well, I would try to set the rights according in my sources (maybe I'll try it when I have a little more spare time). But I am using Windows and netbeans.

Are there any attributes I can set to achive my goal, or is it possible to achive this using ant?

By the way: Are there security related issues with this approach? The script looks for java executable and calls a javabased GUI-installer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change permissions during initialization of the application, the following:

```
String [] command = {"/bin/chmod","+x",full_path_to_install.sh};
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec( command );
pr.waitFor();
```

allows your application to set executable permissions before using the script. It is not executable right after tomcat deployed your war file but just before your application uses it.

Comment: That sounds good. I will look at it more closer next week, since I have to finish another project right now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are invoking the same "install.sh" everytime, you need to set the execute bit only once. Also, the executable bit need to be set only for the user (the command you have provided will set it for everyone).

```
chmod u+x install.sh
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question. See my edit for details.

Comment: About setting executable for everyone: You're totally right about this.  Of course I should only set this right for user(s) that need/ are allowed to execute this script, but I'm in development right now ;) I will take care about permissions when everything works

Comment: Ah, so you want the shell script within the web-inf set to executable ? The only practical way you can do that is via a chmod command in the parent script. But, I have to say that I have never heard of having a shell script placed within a war file.

Comment: Unfortunately right now I don't have a parent script. But probably I will have to write one. The reason for the script within the war-file is for simplicity. This way I don't have to care with version of the application is currently deployed. The script always fits (and I don't have to care about where CATALINA_BASE is, because I am already there... And on top of that: By including this script in my war-file it gets easier to share the application, because it is only one file.